# Laravel - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'active' in migration

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-8 application, I have created users table using migration. How I want to add two new columns. I have this:

```
class AlterTableUsers extends Migration
{
    /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('avatar', 200)->after('password')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('active', 1)->after('avatar')->nullable()->default(0);
        });
    }

    /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('avatar', 200)->after('password')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('active', 1)->after('avatar')->nullable()->default(0);
        });
    }
```

When I did:

```
php artisan migrate
```

I got this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'active' (SQL: alter table `users` add `avatar` varchar(200) null after `password`, add `active` tinyint null default '0' auto_increment primary key after `avatar`)

> 1   C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:465
> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'active'")

> 2   C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:465
> PDO::prepare("alter table `users` add `avatar` varchar(200) null after `password`, add `active` tinyint null default '0' auto_increment primary key after `avatar`")

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Comment: If you have default value, then it would not be nullable `$table->tinyInteger('active', 1)->after('avatar')->default(0);` or, you make it nullable,  then it would not have default value `$table->tinyInteger('active', 1)->after('avatar')->nullable();`

Comment: @EsTeAa - The problem still remains when I did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 errors. In your down function, you have to drop your columns.

```
public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('avatar');
            $table->dropColumn('active');
        });
    }
```

Your problem is this line:

```
$table->tinyInteger('active', 1)->after('avatar')->nullable()->default(0);
```

When you put that `1` in a `tinyInteger` field you are creating an `auto_increment primary key` value that is null, and have a default value. That is the error that appears here:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid
> default value for 'active' (SQL: alter table users add avatar
> varchar(200) null after password, add active tinyint null default '0'
> auto_increment primary key after avatar)

Do you really need the `active` field to be auto_increment or could it just be a tinyInteger? If you change that line to:

```
$table->tinyInteger('active')->after('avatar')->nullable()->default(0);
```

It works.
And if you put like this:

```
$table->tinyIncrements('active')->after('avatar');
```

You will get this error:

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it
> must be defined as a key

Because `users` table already has `id` column

Comment: I don't want to make active auto_increment. I just want to specify the length to be 1. That's why I put 1

Comment: If you want to limit a numeric field, you must use this: `$table->decimal('active', $precision = 1, $scale = 0);`. [Laravel - Migration - Decimal](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-decimal)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you are using sqlite, which only supports one (1) table modification per transaction. Solve it by splitting your up/down methods into multiple `Schema::table` calls

Comment: I am using mysql

Answer (score 0):

If you use nullable, that pretty much takes care of default and default is not required.

```
$table->tinyInteger('active', 1)->after('avatar')->nullable()->default(0);
```

remove the default in both up and down function